# Indexing API 403 Permission denied. Failed to verify the URL ownership

Tags: indexing, google-api, google-indexing-api

I want to execute the code from the example:

```
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();

    // service_account_file.json is the private key that you created         for your service account.
    $client->setAuthConfig('service_account_file.json');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');

    // Get a Guzzle HTTP Client
    $httpClient = $client->authorize();
    $endpoint =         'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';

    // Define contents here. The structure of the content is described in the next step.
    $content = "{
      \"url\": \"http://example.com/jobs/42\", //I used real url from my homepage
      \"type\": \"URL_UPDATED\"
    }";

    $response = $httpClient->post($endpoint, [ 'body' => $content ]);
    $status_code = $response->getStatusCode();
```

But in response, I get an error: 403 "Permission denied. Failed to verify the URL ownership.".

1. I created service account and read the file in my application.
2. Site verified. [screeen1](https://monosnap.com/direct/gLzWbdMx4hEpzq4BOylCQdF8J9wpEV)
3. Access to service account is full. [screeen2](https://monosnap.com/direct/5jjiXsdy3lywDzGEgGqQaNHR7e8iey)
4. I used domain without "www" and https in search console and in my app.
5. Indexing API enabled and requests come.

What else needs to be done and checked to gain access?

**Answer**

Full access !== Owner. I need to read the documentation better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full access !== Owner. I need to read the documentation better.

Comment: Yup, make sure in the google search console under "Users and permissions" you set the licence to "OWNER"

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, your service account should be "owner" (not "full").
With the new search console, it is almost impossible to set the service account to Owner, luckily, you can use the [old Webmasters tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home).

https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/4763732?hl=en

Comment: You literally save my life. Thanks so much for the old Webmasters link!!